# Pythonic way for do math among columns within a MultiIndex dataframe and concat the result as a seperate column in original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to figure out

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Company A','Company B'],['VWAL','Volumn']],names=[u'Entity',u'Indicator'])
rows = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01',periods=6,freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(1,100,(6,4)),index=rows,columns=cols)

In [245]: df
Out[245]: 
Entity      Company A        Company B       
Indicator       VWAL Volumn      VWAL Volumn
2018-01-01        92      3        22     59
2018-01-02        90     67        52     69
2018-01-03        12     10        35     11
2018-01-04        83      7        62      5
2018-01-05        35     74        27     19
2018-01-06        97     50        93     39
```

if i want to calculate 3rd-Column = VWAL+Volumn, 4th-Column=VWAL-Volumn for each company respectively, and concatenate them as separate columns under respective company, what is the most efficient / pythonic way to do this? (note: there could be thousands of Companies, and rows for several years, I am thinking about using generator to iterate over "company" label to save memory and speed up process)

I tried my way as below, but was stuck on dealing with the MultiIndex when concatenating the results.

```
temp = df.loc(axis=1)[:,'VWAL'].values+df.loc(axis=1)[:,'Volumn'].values
df2 = pd.concat([df,temp],axis=1,join='inner',keys=?????)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of MultiIndex in columns and aggregate `sum`
- create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for align data
- [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and sort columns names by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['new']])
print (df1)
           Company A Company B
                 new       new
2018-01-01       160       117
2018-01-02       142       185
2018-01-03       145       107
2018-01-04       144       110
2018-01-05       116       178
2018-01-06       119       124

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)

Entity     Company A             Company B            
Indicator       VWAL Volumn  new      VWAL Volumn  new
2018-01-01        67     93  160        99     18  117
2018-01-02        84     58  142        87     98  185
2018-01-03        97     48  145        74     33  107
2018-01-04        47     97  144        26     84  110
2018-01-05        79     37  116        97     81  178
2018-01-06        69     50  119        56     68  124
```